# Is there documentation for how PPT and Adobe Illustrator parse SVG formats?

Tags: svg, powerpoint, adobe-illustrator

I have a program that exports .SVG files perfectly according to my native desktop viewer or Google Chrome (browser viewer).

However, when I open files in PPT/Illustrator, it doesn't load properly and I can't edit them further.

Is there documentation to learn how to comply with the .SVG filetype those programs expect?

If not, what's the best way to find the team or an engineer working on it to get more info?

Otherwise, it's a matter of wasted time with trial and error.

Comment: The benchmark for a "perfect SVG export" is neither Chrome nor a "native desktop viewer", but the W3C [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/). You might be able to measure your exports against this, but for Microsoft and Adobe programs importing SVGs, you have to search for known bugs.

Comment: @ccprog do you expect these bugs would be publicly available?

Comment: I'm not aware of publicly available bug trackers for both Microsoft Office products and Adobe Illustrator. I suspect searching here on stackoverflow might be your best bet to identify bugs.

Comment: If you can't edit the svg in Illustrator, you exporting application might actually rasterize all elements to an `<image>`  element. Please share one of these files (ideally the most compact one). Otherwise a lot of features supported by modern browsers don't work well in desktop applications (e.g. rotations depending on `rotation-origin`, complex filters etc)

Comment: >> @ccprog do you expect these bugs would be publicly available?
For MS Office/PowerPoint, no.  But if you have repeatable behavior that you suspect is a but, start PowerPoint, choose Help then Send Feedback and report the problem. Put a screenshot of the result you get when importing the SVGs on the screen so your report can include it and ideally, post a couple sample SVGs publicly and include the link in your report. Reports filed this way do get to the dev team.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg more interested in communicating with someone on dev-team and figuring out the hacks rather than sending a bug-report and never getting help

Comment: @jaslibra That'd be ideal, yes. But it's not going to happen. If you want to post an example SVG + screenshot of what you see when you insert it + version and build info on your version of PowerPoint + info on the program that's creating the SVGs, I can probably get it in front of the right person at MS. They DO solicit examples of SVGs that don't fly right so they can improve their import feature.